# Pyvmomi: delete resource pool

Tags: pyvmomi

The documentation and samples do not have any examples of deleting a resource pool...

can anyone point me in the right direction?

is there a method similar to CreateResourcePool(name,spec) ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A `ResourcePool` extends `ManagedEntity` therefore it has the `Destroy_Task` method available to it. Here is the relevant SOAP doc for the ResourcePool: http://www.yavijava.com/docs/vim.ResourcePool.html Im pretty sure in pyVmomi they dont call the method `Destroy_Task` I think its just `Destroy`. You could do a `dir()` on the object to see what methods it has.